# How to send different AJAX URL if input is empty

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making a live search with AJAX that searches all the rows of the SQL column called number and sorts by number. But I cant figure out how to change the SQL sort to another column called wt when the input is empty.

I tried making an JQuery if statement that says, if the the input is empty show a AJAX page that has the SQL sort by wt:

```
//Search filter

function searchFilter(page_num) {

    page_num = page_num?page_num: 0;

    var ItemSearch = $('#ItemSearch').val();

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: 'vendors/php/getSearchData.php',
        data:'page='+page_num+'&ItemSearch='+ItemSearch,
        success: function (html) {
            $('.LoaderContainer').hide();   //Hide infinite scroll
            $('#BodyContainer').html(html);

        }

    });

    // Validating if search box is empty (my issue)
    if (ItemSearch == '') {

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php',
            success: function (html) {
                $('.LoaderContainer').show();   //Show infinite scroll
                $('#BodyContainer').html(html); 

            }

        });

    }

}
```

I expect the output to change from `url: 'vendors/php/getSearchData.php'` to `url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php'` when variable ItemSearch is empty

Comment: So use `else` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variables for the URL and data, so you can set them in `if/else` and then use the same AJAX code.

```js
function searchFilter(page_num) {
  page_num = page_num ? page_num : 0;
  var ItemSearch = $('#ItemSearch').val();
  var url;
  var data;
  if (ItemSearch == '') {
    url = 'vendors/php/NextPage.php';
    data = {
     pageno: parseInt($("#pageno").val()) + 1
    }
  } else {
    url = 'vendors/php/getSearchData.php';
    data = {
      page: page_num,
      ItemSearch: ItemSearch
    };
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(html) {
      $('.LoaderContainer').hide(); //Hide infinite scroll
      $('#BodyContainer').html(html);
    }
  });
}
```

I strongly recommend you use the object form of `data` rather than concatenating strings. jQuery will convert that to a string and encode it properly, which you failed to do.

Comment: What did it do instead of sending different AJAX requests?

Comment: What it’s expected to do is change #BodyContainer to vendors/php/NextPage.php when #ItemSearch (the id for a text input with no search button) is empty. Reason being is #BodyContainer’s default is vendors/php/NextPage.php, I want it to go back to it’s default when the input is empty. Thanks so much for the help by the way

Comment: That's what my code is supposed to do. What is it doing instead when you try it?

Comment: Its not going to NextPage.php when the input is emptied. But I know NextPage.php works fine because it runs before you put anything in said input. Instead it stays on getSearchData.php but without any value, so #BodyContainer is showing content that I dont want to show.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't put the response into `#BodyContainer`. Have you checked the Network tab of DevTools to see what the AJAX response is?

Comment: How does `NetxPage.php` know which page is next? Shouldn't there be a parameter with the page number?

Comment: Pagination.php
`$pageno = $_POST['pageno'];

    $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
...
`
Pagination.js
`//Infinite scroll
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#Loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  
  if (isInView) {
   
   var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val())+1;
   
   $.ajax({
    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'vendors/php/NextPage.php',
    data: { pageno: nextPage },
...`

Comment: You have no `pageno` parameter when calling `NextPage.php`.

Comment: I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, thanks so much for your time and help.